# Spark - unable to save data frame to disk

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am running Spark in standalone mode with Hive catalog. I am trying to load data from an external document and then save it back to disk in Parquet format.

```py
rdd = sc \
    .textFile('/data/source.txt', NUM_SLICES) \
    .map(lambda x: (x[:5], x[6:12], gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(x[13:]))) 

schema = StructType([
    StructField('c1', StringType(), False),
    StructField('c2', StringType(), False),
    StructField('c3', ArrayType(StringType(), True), False),
])

data = sql_context.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)

data.write.mode('overwrite').parquet('/data/some_dir')
```

When I am trying to read that file back, it fails with:

```
AnalysisException: 'Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.;'
```

Which looks like it just can't property parse the location or the files.

Now if i look at the location on all 3 worker nodes, it looks like:

```
clush -ab 'locate some_file'
---------------
master
---------------
/data/some_file
/data/some_file/._SUCCESS.crc
/data/some_file/_SUCCESS
---------------
worker1
---------------
/data/some_file
/data/some_file/_temporary
/data/some_file/_temporary/0
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/_temporary
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/task_20180511211832_0010_m_000000
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/task_20180511211832_0010_m_000039
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/task_20180511211832_0010_m_000000/.part-00000-1b2764a6-28a3-4ba2-9493-766074eef4d5-c000.snappy.parquet.crc
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/task_20180511211832_0010_m_000000/part-00000-1b2764a6-28a3-4ba2-9493-766074eef4d5-c000.snappy.parquet
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/task_20180511211832_0010_m_000039/.part-00039-1b2764a6-28a3-4ba2-9493-766074eef4d5-c000.snappy.parquet.crc
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/task_20180511211832_0010_m_000039/part-00039-1b2764a6-28a3-4ba2-9493-766074eef4d5-c000.snappy.parquet
---------------
worker2
---------------
/data/some_file
/data/some_file/_temporary
/data/some_file/_temporary/0
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/_temporary
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/task_20180511211832_0010_m_000011
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/task_20180511211832_0010_m_000017
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/task_20180511211832_0010_m_000029
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/task_20180511211832_0010_m_000038
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/task_20180511211832_0010_m_000011/.part-00011-1b2764a6-28a3-4ba2-9493-766074eef4d5-c000.snappy.parquet.crc
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/task_20180511211832_0010_m_000011/part-00011-1b2764a6-28a3-4ba2-9493-766074eef4d5-c000.snappy.parquet
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/task_20180511211832_0010_m_000017/.part-00017-1b2764a6-28a3-4ba2-9493-766074eef4d5-c000.snappy.parquet.crc
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/task_20180511211832_0010_m_000017/part-00017-1b2764a6-28a3-4ba2-9493-766074eef4d5-c000.snappy.parquet
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/task_20180511211832_0010_m_000029/.part-00029-1b2764a6-28a3-4ba2-9493-766074eef4d5-c000.snappy.parquet.crc
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/task_20180511211832_0010_m_000029/part-00029-1b2764a6-28a3-4ba2-9493-766074eef4d5-c000.snappy.parquet
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/task_20180511211832_0010_m_000038/.part-00038-1b2764a6-28a3-4ba2-9493-766074eef4d5-c000.snappy.parquet.crc
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/task_20180511211832_0010_m_000038/part-00038-1b2764a6-28a3-4ba2-9493-766074eef4d5-c000.snappy.parquet
---------------
worker3
---------------
/data/some_file
/data/some_file/_temporary
/data/some_file/_temporary/0
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/_temporary
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/task_20180511211832_0010_m_000040
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/task_20180511211832_0010_m_000043
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/task_20180511211832_0010_m_000046
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/task_20180511211832_0010_m_000040/.part-00040-1b2764a6-28a3-4ba2-9493-766074eef4d5-c000.snappy.parquet.crc
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/task_20180511211832_0010_m_000040/part-00040-1b2764a6-28a3-4ba2-9493-766074eef4d5-c000.snappy.parquet
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/task_20180511211832_0010_m_000043/.part-00043-1b2764a6-28a3-4ba2-9493-766074eef4d5-c000.snappy.parquet.crc
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/task_20180511211832_0010_m_000043/part-00043-1b2764a6-28a3-4ba2-9493-766074eef4d5-c000.snappy.parquet
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/task_20180511211832_0010_m_000046/.part-00046-1b2764a6-28a3-4ba2-9493-766074eef4d5-c000.snappy.parquet.crc
/data/some_file/_temporary/0/task_20180511211832_0010_m_000046/part-00046-1b2764a6-28a3-4ba2-9493-766074eef4d5-c000.snappy.parquet
```

I can't understand why it saves this into '_temporary' and not into persistent folder.

Let me know if you need additional context.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** To save and load data in distributed mode you'll need a distributed file system. Local storage is not sufficient.

> I can't understand why it saves this into '_temporary' and not into persistent folder.

That's because you don't have distributed file system. In that case, each executor can finish its own part, but Spark won't be able to correctly finalize the job.

Also, because each executor has access only to a part of result, it won't be possible to load data back with Spark.

Comment: Indeed, I understand why that is. Still I actually hoped that by simulating distributed storage by making the locally attached volumes identical across nodes will be good enough, but apparently - it's not. After adding NAS mounts to every node (which is my distributed file system) - everything worked. I find it a bit unintuitive and wanted to understand it better. So any useful reading that you can point me too (other then anything easily googleable) would be of help.

Comment: I am not sure if there is any explicit documentation here. Writes are just a weird behavior (I've seen it explained on SO, but I cannot find the question). For reads each node has to be able to access all chunks of data, and this condition is not satisfied when data is in pieces on local storage.